# localStorage performance: one big object or several smaller ones?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I need to save locally some JSONs I get from an external servers data, so that I will no problem if those are eventually erased. I'm using `localStorage`.

Since now I have more categories of this data, I am not sure if is it better to save all the data as one big localstorage object of objects, or make one localstorage.CatXXXX for each XXXX category.

Is one better than the other? Do do they compare on performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is stored in LocalStorage as key value pairs, as strings, with no nesting.

If you store super nested objects, you'll need to fetch them first, and then parse them before they can be used. This will consume a teeny bit more time than if you use actual key value pairs, in which case you won't need to parse anything (unless you store some numbers that you want to typecast and such)

Here is some documentation on the implementation of the spec from [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html), [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197050(VS.85).aspx) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: I'm using angular's `.fromJson()` and `.toJson()` for deal with the string-to-array conversion. But I think convert more and more categories when no all will be used is a waste of time (milliseconds but time) and resources. I suppose I will go with several localStorage "objects"

Comment: Correct. Parsing is costly, and tough the consequences aren't immediately apparent, they might crop up at a later stage once the application is scaled up!